# Python Pycharm: Describe Dataframe not Shown

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

Within Pycharm Professional 2017.3 (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3],"b":[4,5,6]})
abc=df2.describe()
```

generates a new Pandas dataframe `abc`.

If I want to view this dataframe in the SciView tool, nothing is shown:

[image: screenshot]

If I write the name of the dataframe (abc) and specify a format (e.g. %) in the two fields in the bottom, still nothing is shown.

As expected, printing works:

```
print(abc)
```

---

```
         a    b
count  3.0  3.0
mean   2.0  5.0
std    1.0  1.0
min    1.0  4.0
25%    1.5  4.5
50%    2.0  5.0
75%    2.5  5.5
max    3.0  6.0
```

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27967

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a bug.  It appears to be related to the `%` in the index.

With this code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]})
abc = df2.describe()
abc_fixed = abc.reset_index().replace(
    {'25%': '25_percent', '50%': '50_percent', '75%': '75_percent'}
).set_index('index')
```

`abc` will not display, but `abc_fixed` will display.